# How to add a progress bar in a Python command-line URL downloader?

Tags: python, command-line, download, progress-bar

I have made a simple command-line URL downloader in Python. When the user supplies a URL it reads the file from web and saves it in a string, then saves the string in a file on the computer.

I want to add a progress bar. How should I go about it?

Comment: What UI does your downloader have at the moment? Is it a command-line script?

Comment: ya command line it is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Figure out the total size of the file you're downloading. This is often present in the HTTP header `Content-Length` (which is in bytes).
2. Keep count of the total data downloaded so far.
3. The amount of the progress bar that should be filled at any moment is given by the formula: `(downloaded so far) / (total size)` which is a number between 0 and 1, inclusive.

Comment: i can not find out the size of data downloaded as i am copying the file in a string and until the copying stops i can out find out its size

Comment: @user1065734 - The very concept of progress bar is based upon the idea of displaying the **amount of progress** against the **amount of job needed to complete the task**. Not having either of these two makes impossible to produce a progress bar (you might wish to look in [throbbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throbber) though).

Answer (score 3):

This is a **very basic** implementation of a progress bar on the command line:

```
>>> def progress_bar(percentage, length):
...     filled = int(length / 100.0 * percentage)
...     return '#' * filled + '_' * (length - filled)
... 
>>> progress_bar(100, 80)
'################################################################################'
>>> progress_bar(10, 80)
'########________________________________________________________________________'
>>> progress_bar(0, 80)
'________________________________________________________________________________'
>>> progress_bar(50, 40)
'####################____________________'
>>>
```

If you wanted it to appear statically (i.e. instead of outputting a new line for each update of the bar, to overwrite the same line over and over) you should wrap this into some [curses](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html) handling.